# .htaccess redirect 403 error files to 404 error document

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I have a folder named `control` which is contained in the root project folder named `project`, so the path on localhost forms like this for the `control` folder: `http://localhost/project/control`

In the `control` folder I put a `.htaccess` file that has the content:

```
RewriteEngine On
deny from all
```

At the project root folder i.e `project` folder i have another `.htaccess` file that contains the main code, including this 404 error redirection code:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f  
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d  
RewriteRule ^  errordocs/404.php [L]
```

Now what I want to do is that whenever `403` error is encountered when opening the `control` folder it should rewrite it to the same `errordocs/404.php` page.

Comment: Hello, Sourabh. Next unclear question:) if `deny from all` then in root htaccess rewrite /control/* to erorr404 ?

Comment: you mean to say do this: `^control/(.*)$     errordocs/404.php [L]`

Comment: @splash58, am i right?

Comment: Yes. or, knowing your tricky conditions :) ,  i don't say leading ^ then /project /control will work too `control/(.*)$ errordocs/404.php [L]`

Comment: that did that trick but it has re written all the urls that were being used :), so i cannot use it

Comment: More clear please. what is wrong?

Comment: previous url that were being used like eg: `contol/test.php` are now become useless as i have all `RewriteRule ^control/         ^errordocs/404.php [L]`. All the urls in that are now rewriting to errordocument/404.php

Comment: `deny from all` give the same result, only 403

Comment: @splash58, i solved my problem and posted the answer below if you have time do look at it and see if that will cause any error

Answer (score 4):

You can match a statuscode with an output page with `ErrorDocument`

```
ErrorDocument 404 errordocs/404.php
ErrorDocument 403 errordocs/404.php
```

Comment: The problem is that error documents always start with document root like this `ErrorDocument 404 /errordocus/404.php` which i do not want to do. I want to use a relative path instead of a path from document root

Comment: You only need to specify `ErrorDocument` once, for instance in your document root. The path shouldn't pose any issues.

Comment: You answer will not redirect to the error page but will show the output as `errordocs/404.php` on the page because the ErrroDocument should be given always from the document root

Comment: Redirecting to a 404 page is possible but not recommended. This is not how HTTP was designed. You might run into issues with SEO and it gives a terrible user experience.

Comment: i do not want to show a blank pages for `403` what do you suggest me to do?

Comment: You don't have to show a blank page this is why you define an `ErrorDocument`. Make sure `errordocs/404.php` returns content.

Comment: it is written as `ErrorDocument 404 /project/errordocs/404.php`, i do not want to hardcode `/project` here.as my project root folder name is `/project`

Comment: Can you explain why you don't want to hardcode `/project`?

Comment: because the `/project` folder name  will keep on changing and all users do not know how to configure `.htaccess`. I want to do somthing as being done for 404 in my question.

Comment: That seems like a strange problem to have. If you can't trust your users to configure their `.htaccess` properly how can you trust them to implement an `errordocs/404.php` properly? If `/project` is the root of your project the `.htaccess` should be inside that folder.

Comment: everything will be there in the project root folder, error documents and other things. Error document 404 is working dynamically with the rewrite rule without using `ErrorDocument`, i am stuck with 403.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to solve my problem, i am trying to explain it here, so that it might be helpful to others also, it is working fine for me.

in my `project/control/.htaccess` file i put the code:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^$   ../errordocs/404.php [L]
```

So whenever the user types the url `localhost/project/control/` then he will see the custom 404.php file from errordocs folder which is one directory back, as my aim was to prevent direct access to the control folder. I did not use `deny from all` instead of that used the above procedure so that i can use the custom error pages for the 403 error, that will be independent of the document root path. Now my project folder can be named to any name the user wishes.

**Note:** This procedure will return 200 instead of actual 403 error. To return 403 and 404 use the below respective code:

403

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^$  ../errordocs/404.php [L]
RewriteRule ^$ - [R=403,NC,L]
```

404

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^$  ../errordocs/404.php [L]
RewriteRule ^$ - [R=404,NC,L]
```

Comment: Hmm that will return status=200 instead of status=403 to user.

Comment: @anubhava, yes that is the only problem with this i think, i do not think that is a very big issue what do you say?

Comment: well basically i do not want to allow search engine index this path `http://domain.com/project/control/` as this contains the controller code, this functionality is for security issue. I want to make it invisible. Is this fine now?. I also added this `RewriteRule ^/ - [L,R=403]` in the `.htaccess` file to return 403 error, is this fine?

Comment: well it is for preventing hackers to access that folder, not totally secure i know, for good search engines we can use `robots.txt`

Comment: write RewriteRule `^ ../errordocs/404.php [L]` - i suppose ^$ select only empty URI

Answer (score 0):

redirect 403 to 404 in htaccess

```
ErrorDocument 403 /yourfoldererror/404.php
```

And in your 404.php add php code like this :

```
<?php http_response_code(404);?><!DOCTYPE html><html ....
```

With that code, the response will not 403, but 404